# HTTP 500 error from jQuery AJAX call when passing html dates into django model

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

i'm working with a date selector form in html (see pic below) and i'd like to pass this data into my django model.

[image]

i've successfully passed in form data to my django model (from an option class), with similar code. however, when passing in the selected dates, i get a `XHR POST http://127.0.0.1:1234/` error.

i'm quite new to AJAX, but i've heard that i should stay away from creating XHR objects. have i created one here, and how do i avoid creating them? thanks!

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-9">
                        <div class="date">
                            <br>
                            <h3>Select to view distance and orders by timeframe</h3>
                            <form method="POST">
                                <label for="start">Start date:</label>
                                <input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-12-01" min="2018-12-01"
                                    max="2019-06-30">

                                <label for="end">End date:</label>
                                <input type="date" id="end" name="trip-end" value="2018-12-01" min="2018-12-01"
                                    max="2019-07-01">
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            $("#start").change(function () { // calling select id
                                const start_date = $(this).val();  // get the selected subject ID from the HTML dropdown list 
                                $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: '',
                                    data: {
                                        'start_date': start_date,       // add the order id to the POST parameters
                                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{csrf_token}}",
                                    },
                                    success: function (data) {   // `data` is from `homepage` view function
                                        console.log("this block of code isn't useless!!")
                                        console.log(data.start_date)
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                            $("#end").change(function () { // calling select id
                                const end_date = $(this).val();  // get the selected subject ID from the HTML dropdown list 
                                $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: '',
                                    data: {
                                        'end_date': end_date,       // add the order id to the POST parameters
                                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{csrf_token}}",
                                    },
                                    success: function (data) {   // `data` is from `homepage` view function
                                        console.log("this block of code isn't useless!!")
                                        console.log(data.end_date)
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You are getting server error i.e: something wrong at your server code .

Comment: i tried clearing the cache and deleting the cookies but it didn't work